# Mostrar div no onclick independente do botão clicado

Tags: javascript, html

Conheço pouco de `javascript` e em minha página tenho um botão que, quando clicado, chama um `div`. Até aqui tudo bem, mas a função pega o `id` do botão, ou seja, se eu por mais de um botão na página e precisar chamar o `div` não vai funcionar. Preciso mudar a função para pegar o botão por parâmetro no `onclick` e não fixo por `id`.

Como está:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitbtn">//Gostaria de chamar a função no onclick passando qualquer botão como parametro
```

Função:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#submitbtn").click(function () {//Aqui seria a passagem do parâmetro
        $("#loading").fadeIn();
        var opts = {
            lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 7, // The length of each line
            width: 4, // The line thickness
            radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        };
        var target = document.getElementById('loading');
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione uma classe nos botões e utilize essa classe no javascript, como por exemplo:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="botaoMostraDiv">
```

e então mude o seu javascript de `("#submitbtn").click(function () { ...`

para `$(".botaoMostraDiv").click(function () {...`

Comment: Valeu Marciano, era isso mesmo!

Comment: Marque a mesma como aceita então ;)

Comment: Desculpa, ainda sou novo por aqui rs.

Comment: dá uma olhada no [tour] então!